# Assigning a function (which is assigned dynamically) along with specific parameters, to a variable.

Tags: python

Ok, so here's the deal, say I have a function( take_action ), that calls another function. But we don't know which function take_action is going to call.

I had that part figured out thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246000/python-calling-functions-dynamically), the thing is, on that question they deal with functions that take no arguments, my take_action could take one of several different functions that are quite different from each other, with completely different actions taken, different arguments.

Now for some example code:

```
def take_action():
    action['action']()
    #does other stuff with 'other_stuff_in_the_dic'

def move(x,y):
    #stuff happens

action = {'action': move, 'other_stuff_in_the_dic': 'stuff' }
```

(In this case the 'action' would be move, but like I said, that's assigned dynamically depending on certain user input)

What I would like to do, is something like this:

```
action = { 'action': move(2,3), 'other_stuff': 'stuff' }
```

(Obviously that calls the function there, since it has the (), hence it wouldn't work)

I'm only a beginner programmer, and the only thing I thought of is using a list, which is in another key inside the dic, but that would just pass one list argument, instead of each content of the list being passed on as an argument.

What would be a way to achieve this, so the 'action' key (or the dictionary on another key?) also stores the arguments it should use when I call it on take_action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to store functions with their arguments:

```
from functools import partial

action = {'action': partial(move, 2, 3), 'other_stuff': 'stuff'}
```

Calling `action['action']()` results in `move(2, 3)` being called.