# call defining by variable in python

Tags: python, function

I have two files

```
test_def.py
def hi_test(a):
    return a
```

test_run.py

```
from test_def import hi_test
a = 'hi'
b = 'test'
c = 'lion'

run = "{0}_{1}".format(a, b)
run1 = run(c)
print run1
```

it is printing hi_test(lion) instead of executing / calling def function.
can anyone help on this to execute the def function ?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246000/python-calling-functions-dynamically

Answer (score 3):

```
import test_def
a = 'hi'
b = 'test'
c = 'lion'

run = "{0}_{1}".format(a, b)
run1 = getattr(test_def, run)(c)
print run1
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be archive by the following method.

```
import test_def
a = 'hi'
b = 'test'
c = 'lion'

run = "{0}_{1}".format(a, b)
run1 = getattr(test_def,run)
run2 = run1(c)
print run2
```

Answer (score 0):

test_def.py

```
def hi_test(a):
    print a
```

test_run.py

```
from test_def import hi_test

a = 'hi'
b = 'test'
c = 'lion'

run = "{0}_{1}".format(a, b)
exec("%s('%s')"%(run, c))
```

Although, the first answer is better