# is there a way to call functions dynamically with dynamic parameter values in python?

Tags: python

I am using python 3 with jupyter notebook.
I implemented simple widgets that take method name and parameter values as inputs from users.
Parameters of the method depends on the method itself

For example, in a run event both of the functions below can be called according to methods and parameter values user chose

```
KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init=10).fit(X)

AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=12, affinity='euclidean').fit(X)
```

I can form the parameters as strings but I could not pass it to functions.
is there a way to execute those functions in string form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Python functions dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246000/how-to-call-python-functions-dynamically)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291242/python-dynamically-create-function-at-runtime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: dynamically create function at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291242/python-dynamically-create-function-at-runtime)

Comment: ``exec("Your_Code_as_String")``

Comment: seems like it doesn't work

aa = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=12).fit(df_raw)

bb = exec("AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=12).fit(df_raw)")
display(type(aa))
display(type(bb))

sklearn.cluster._agglomerative.AgglomerativeClustering

NoneType