# Is it possible to import modules and call functions based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import, python-module

Is it possible to call modules and functions with user input in Python?

For example:

```
a = input("Module: ")

import a

b = input("Function: ")

a.b()
```

Comment: I think these could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Python functions dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246000/how-to-call-python-functions-dynamically)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. The links you posted worked.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
eval(f'import {a}')
eval(f'{a}.{b}')
```

but I higly recommend you not to just eval random user input.

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem in different ways, by the way, when I use eval for import, it raises syntax error.