# Appwrite in a docker container with a simple python throws security error... I think

Tags: python, docker, appwrite

I created an appwrite docker, and created a project and api in the docker.

I'm trying to use this python code:

```
from appwrite.client import Client
from appwrite.services.users import Users

client = Client()


(client
  .set_endpoint('https://localhost/v1') # Your API Endpoint
  .set_project('testwriter') # Your project ID
  .set_key('b5b793e92b7f1badf34c3ef0ebfd475418a2372306ea4094eb5efb20bdc76e283e28345801d34c441149cc796f0ea7608ff0696a2121f577ca2beada75f904a46b1293a1d57699eed9750a2f12c4daa261e73231f6479e425276e7df053305118080f8280e7462b01b45349310f7086fc90a606d0d5ff2e102d7119ff627e0d4') # Your secret API key
)

users = Users(client)

result = users.create('email@example.com', 'password')
```

I'm getting the following error output though and I can't figure it out, although I think it's because I need to create a ca key or something and add it to docker?  Can somebody suggest the next steps?:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 699, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 382, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 1010, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 416, in connect
> self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py",
> line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
> ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py",
> line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
> "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py",
> line 500, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py",
> line 1040, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py",
> line 1309, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 439, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 755, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
> line 574, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /v1/users (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,
> '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self
> signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appwrite/client.py",
> line 79, in call
> response = requests.request(  # call method dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246075/2299554   File
> "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 542, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 655, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 514, in send
> raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /v1/users (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,
> '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self
> signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/vw/DEV/python/test-appwrite/test_appwrite/run.py", line 15, in
>
> result = users.create('email@example.com', 'password')   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appwrite/services/users.py",
> line 52, in create
> return self.client.call('post', path, {   File "/Users/vw/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-appwrite-XiyGxB_m-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/appwrite/client.py",
> line 106, in call
> raise AppwriteException(e)

Answer (score 1):

I found how to make it work with python.  Just add .set_self_signed(True) as part of the call.