# format function name as string and then call it? fn_call = f"static_{dynamic}" then fn_call()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

I have a series of functions that do some data cleaning.

```
def clean_field_1(field_1): 
    return field_1
```

for example.

When looping through a dict of fields, field_1 may not be there. But if it is I'd like to call `clean_field_1()`.

```
for field in dict_object:
    fn_call = f"clean_{field}"
    fn_call(field)
```

That's to illustrate the goal. In this case that final line errors because the str object is not callable.

Or it's possible that my approach is totally off base and I need a different one. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Would `exec` work? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/

Comment: Untested `locals.get(fn_call, globals.get(fn_call))(field)`

Comment: Or if your functions are in a different module `getattr(your_module, fn_call)(field)`

Comment: I didn't find links in the Question Closed notice helpful but I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246000/how-to-call-python-functions-dynamically